# leaflet show miles/kilometers

Tags: leaflet, maps

Googlemaps shows you how large an area is on a map by showing a small bar with the number of miles/kilometers at the bottem left. Does leaflet also support this somehow?

I do not see it listed in the docs at leafletjs but it seems like something that the library should support.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think you are looking for the scale bar. Use `L.control.scale().addTo(map);` ([ref. Leaflet documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-scale))